# How to get current url in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, url, scripting, chef-infra

I am trying to create a Chef recipe for error handling, this recipe will be ran through Rundeck. If an error occurs throughout this run I want specific information to be logged including the Rundeck URL which the script is running on.

Is there such a way in Ruby to get the current URL?

Comment: did you get it solved?

Comment: No unfortunately this did not work :(

Answer (score 3):

Depends on which type of URL you want:

For Realtive URL : `request.request_uri`

For Absolute URL : `request.original_url`

Implementation :

```
def original_url
  base_url + original_fullpath
end
```

If you are on rails 3 : `request.fullpath`